# Why retain/release rather than new/delete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reference-counting

I'm newbie to objective-C, I feel comportable in C++.

My question is: 
**Why language designer of obj-c proper to use retain/release rather then use new/delete(=alloc/dealloc) only?**

Maybe my brain is fit to new/delete only memory management, I can not understand why I should manage reference counts, I think I know when object have to be alloc/dealloc with my C++ experence.

(Yes, I spend 4 hours to debug reference count problem, it is resolved by 1 line "release")

Can anyone explain me what is better when we use reference counter? (in programming language respects) I think I can manage lifecycle of object by new/delete, but I can't with reference counting.

I need long article that explains why reference counter is useful, if you have link.

P.S: I heard about Compile-time Automatic Reference Counting at WWDC 2011, it is really awesome, it can be reason of use of reference counter, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an objective answer to your question (pun semi-intended). I don't think there is an Obj-C programmer out there who will rush unreservedly to the defence of reference counting - its a royal PITA to be honest. I would recommend code profiler (Product->Profile) in Xcode 4 to save you time fixing reference count issues and premature releases (pun definitely not intended). Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that it is a way to manage object lifetimes without requiring "ownership" as one does with C++.

When creating an object using `new` in C++, something has to know when to `delete` that object later. Often this is straightforward, but it can be difficult when an object can be passed around and shared by many different "owners" with differing lifetimes.

With reference counting, as long as any other object refers to the object, it stays alive.  When all other objects remove their references, it disappears.  There are drawbacks to this approach (the debugging of retain/release and reference cycles being the most obvious), but it is a useful alternative to fully automatic garbage collection.

Objective-C is not the only language to use reference counting. In C++, it is common to use `std::shared_ptr`, which is the standard reference-counted smart pointer template.  Windows Component Object Model programming requires it.  Many languages use automated reference-counting behind the scenes as a garbage-collection strategy.

The Wikipedia article is a good place to start looking for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: Thanks for answer, I really understood what is "ownership" of object allocating/deallocating. anyway, can someone let me know how does Automatic Reference Counting work? (or helpful material to read.) I'm really imagine how it can be work on compile time!

Comment: The only currently-public info on ARC is at the LLVM website: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html. If you are a member of Apple's developer program, you can read NDA info and watch the WWDC sessions at the developer site.